# Rescale for NBA heatmap: dplyr equivalent to plyr function?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, name-conflict

There is this great example of how to use ggplot2 to create a heat map the 'R; way: [Rheatmap](http://flowingdata.com/2010/01/21/how-to-make-a-heatmap-a-quick-and-easy-solution/) which provides a link to the raw data and the source code.

There was a followup using ggplot2: [ggplot2](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/) which lays out the ggplot2 code.

At key points the ggplot2 code uses reshape2 and plyr.

```
nba.m <- melt(nba)
nba.m <- ddply(nba.m, .(variable), transform,rescale = rescale(value))
```

My goal is to duplicate these calculations using tidyr and dplyr.

```
 nba.m <- melt(nba)
```

has a tidyr equivalent in:

```
 nba.g <- gather(nba, Name)
```

What is the dplyr equivalent to this line?

```
nba.m <- ddply(nba.m, .(variable), transform,rescale = rescale(value))
```

eipi10 kindly suggested

```
nba.m2 <- nba.m %>%group_by(Name) %>% mutate(rescale=rescale(value))
```

However, it looks like the rescale calculation is not occuring in quite the same way:

```
> head(nba.m)
        Name variable value   rescale
1   Dwyane Wade         G    79 0.9473684
2  LeBron James         G    81 0.9824561
3   Kobe Bryant         G    82 1.0000000
4 Dirk Nowitzki         G    81 0.9824561
5 Danny Granger         G    67 0.7368421
6  Kevin Durant         G    74 0.8596491
> head(nba.m2)
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: Name

        Name Name.1 value   rescale
1   Dwyane Wade       G    79 0.9634146
2  LeBron James       G    81 0.9878049
3   Kobe Bryant       G    82 1.0000000
4 Dirk Nowitzki       G    81 0.9878049
5 Danny Granger       G    67 0.8170732
6  Kevin Durant       G    74 0.9024390
>
```

What is missing?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: `nba.m = nba.m %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(rescale=rescale(value))`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need write `dplyr::mutate`, not `mutate`.

I presume you loaded `plyr` and `dplyr` in the same session.
`dplyr` and `plyr` are conflict the following objects:
`arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise, summarize`